# Visual Fox Pro Automation

Tags: ms-word, automation, visual-foxpro

I wrote this code to automate in Word from Visual Fox Pro. I put between the escapes `<|<` and `>|>` some VFP code (like take some values from tables and so on). At the press of a button, the code scans all of the document and, when finding these escapes, evaluates the instructions between. The last two `FOR` loops eliminate the escape strings.

The code works, but I ask. Is there a better way to do what I look for?

```vb
LOCAL oWord, oDocument, oRange, Lc_start, Lc_expr, Lc_ris, Ln_count, Lc_val
DIMENSION Lc_funct[1]

Lc_expr = ""
Ln_count = 1

oWord = CREATEOBJECT("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = .T.
cFile = GETFILE()

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(m.cFile)

oRange = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range()
    nWordCount = oRange.Words.Count
    oRange.Collapse(1)
    FOR nWord = 1 TO m.nWordCount-1
    oRange.Expand(2)
    cWord = oRange.Text
    DO CASE

    CASE m.cWord = "<|<"
        Lc_start = .T.
        Lc_Expr = ""

    CASE m.cWord = ">|>"
        Lc_start = .F.
        Lc_funct[Ln_count] = Lc_Expr
        Ln_count = Ln_count + 1
        DIMENSION Lc_funct[Ln_count]

    CASE m.Lc_start
        Lc_expr = Lc_expr + m.cWord

    OTHERWISE
        *do anything

    ENDCASE

    oRange.Collapse(0)
    ENDFOR


    FOR i = 1 TO Ln_count-1
    oRange = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range()
        oRange.Find.Text = Lc_funct[i]
        oRange.Find.Replacement.Text = EVALUATE(Lc_funct[i])
        lFound = oRange.Find.Execute( , , , , , , , , , , 2 )
    ENDFOR

    FOR i = 1 TO Ln_count-1
    oRange = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range()
        oRange.Find.Text = "<|<"
        oRange.Find.Replacement.Text = ""
        lFound = oRange.Find.Execute( , , , , , , , , , , 2 )
    ENDFOR

    FOR i = 1 TO Ln_count-1
        oRange = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range()
        oRange.Find.Text = ">|>"
        oRange.Find.Replacement.Text = ""
        lFound = oRange.Find.Execute( , , , , , , , , , , 2 )
    ENDFOR
MESSAGEBOX("DONE")
```

Comment: Is this real VBA or something closely related like vbscript? Don't recognise `DIMENSION` or `OTHERWISE` and there's no `Set` keyword used || Oh I see, `VFP` is a [programming language](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_FoxPro)

Comment: [Cross-posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56181607/1014587)

Comment: I recommend reading up on the `Range.Find` method, it's a lot more powerful than just find/replace. For starters, there's no need to loop in your last 2 find/replaces, since you use `wdReplaceAll`, it should remove all matches. In fact you can narrow it down further, with some [wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm): `oRange.Find.Execute FindText:= "[\<\>]|[\<\>]", MatchWildcards:= True, ReplaceWith:= "", Replace:= 2`. That will catch `<|<` or `>|>`. You can probably eliminate looping altogether with some judicious `.Find`. (NB assuming VFP supports named arguments)

Comment: Where I can find some good documentation about word automation? there is something, but I need more specific analysis... By the way, thank you for your time, will try to implement this modifications...